# Zend Form Duplicate Entry Email Exception

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Having a registration zend form in view looks like this :

```
<?php 
    $form = $this->form;
    if(isset($form)) $form->prepare();
    $form->setAttribute('action', $this->url(NULL,
    array('controller' => 'register', 'action' => 'process')));
    echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
?>
<dl class="form-signin">
<dd><?php
    echo $this->formElement($form->get('name_reg'));
    echo $this->formElementErrors($form->get('name_reg'));
?></dd>

<dd><?php
    echo $this->formElement($form->get('email_reg'));
    echo $this->formElementErrors($form->get('email_reg'));
?></dd>

<dd><?php
    echo $this->formElement($form->get('password_reg'));
    echo $this->formElementErrors($form->get('password_reg'));
?></dd>

<dd><?php
    echo $this->formElement($form->get('confirm_password_reg'));
    echo $this->formElementErrors($form->get('confirm_password_reg'));
?></dd>
<br>
<dd><?php
    echo $this->formElement($form->get('send_reg'));
    echo $this->formElementErrors($form->get('send_reg'));
?></dd>
<?php echo $this->form()->closeTag() ?>
```

And RegisterController as following.

```
<?php
namespace Test\Controller;


use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Zend\Session\Container; 

use Test\Form\RegisterForm;
use Test\Form\RegisterFilter;

use Test\Form\LoginFormSm;
use Test\Form\LoginFilter;

use Test\Model\User;
use Test\Model\UserTable;

class RegisterController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->layout('layout/register');
        $form = new RegisterForm();
        $form_sm = new LoginFormSm();
        $viewModel = new ViewModel(array(
                            'form' => $form,
                            'form_sm' =>$form_sm,
                            ));
        return $viewModel;
    }


    public function processAction()
    {
        $this->layout('layout/register');

        if (!$this->request->isPost()) {
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute(NULL,
                array( 'controller' => 'index'
                )
            );
        }
        $form = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('RegisterForm');    
        $form->setData($this->request->getPost());

        if (!$form->isValid()) {
            $model = new ViewModel(array(
                'form' => $form,
            ));
            $model->setTemplate('test/register/index');
            return $model;
        }       

        // Creating New User
        $this->createUser($form->getData());
        return $this->redirect()->toRoute(NULL, array (
            'controller' => 'auth' ,
            ));
    }

    protected function createUser(array $data)
    {
        $userTable = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('UserTable');
        $user = new User(); 
        $user->exchangeArray($data);
        $userTable->saveUser($user);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Also a RegisterForm where are declared all variables shown in index. Also RegisterFilter as following:

```
<?php
namespace Test\Form;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;
class RegisterFilter extends InputFilter
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'email_reg',
            'required' => true,
            'filters' => array(
                array(
                    'name' => 'StripTags',
                ),
                array(
                    'name' => 'StringTrim',
                ),
            ),
            'validators' => array(
                array(
                'name' => 'EmailAddress',
                'options' => array(
                    'domain' => true,
                    'messages' => array(
                            \Zend\Validator\EmailAddress::INVALID_FORMAT => 'Email address format is invalid'
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
                array(
                'name' => 'AbstractDb',
                'options' => array(
                    'domain' => true,
                    'messages' => array(
                            \Zend\Validator\Db\AbstractDb::ERROR_RECORD_FOUND => 'Current Email Already registered'
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ));
        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'name_reg',
            'required' => true,
            'filters' => array(
                array(
                    'name' => 'StripTags',
                ),
                array(
                    'name' => 'StringTrim',
                ),
            ),
            'validators' => array(
                array(
                    'name' => 'StringLength',
                    'options' => array(
                        'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                        'min' => 2,
                        'max' => 140,
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ));
        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'password_reg',
            'required' => true,
            'validators' => array(
                array(
                    'name' => 'StringLength',
                    'options' =>array(
                        'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                        'min' => 6,
                        'messages' => array(
                            \Zend\Validator\StringLength::TOO_SHORT => 'Password is too short; it must be at least %min% ' . 'characters'
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
                array(
                    'name' => 'Regex',
                    'options' =>array(
                        'pattern' => '/[A-Z]\d|\d[A-Z]/',
                        'messages' => array(
                            \Zend\Validator\Regex::NOT_MATCH => 'Password must contain at least 1 digit and 1 upper-case letter'
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ));
        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'confirm_password_reg',
            'required' => true,
            'validators' => array(
                array(
                    'name' => 'Identical',
                    'options' => array(
                    'token' => 'password_reg', // name of first password field
                    'messages' => array(
                            \Zend\Validator\Identical::NOT_SAME => "Passwords Doesn't Match"
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ));
    }
}
```

***Problem***
All i need is to throw a message when somebody tries to register and that e-mail is already registered. Tried with **\Zend\Validator\Db\AbstractDb** and added following validator to email in RegisterFilter as following

```
array(
    'name' => 'AbstractDb',
    'options' => array(
        'domain' => true,
         'messages' => array(
             \Zend\Validator\Db\AbstractDb::ERROR_RECORD_FOUND => 'Current Email Already registered'
         ),
    ),
),
```

But that seems not to work.

*Question*: Is there a way to implement this validator in RegisterController?

**Additional.**

I've deleted from RegisterFilert validator and put inside Module.ph

```
'EmailValidation' => function ($sm) {
    $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
    $validator = new RecordExists(
        array(
        'table'   => 'user',
        'field'   => 'email',
        'adapter' => $dbAdapter
        )
    );
return $validator;
},
```

And call it from RegisterController

```
    $validator = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('EmailValidation');    
    if (!$validator->isValid($email)) {
        // email address is invalid; print the reasons
        $model = new ViewModel(array(
            'error' => $validator->getMessages(),
            'form' => $form,
        ));
        $model->setTemplate('test/register/index');
        return $model;
    }
```

And when i use print_r inside view to check for it shows.

Array ( [noRecordFound] => No record matching the input was found ).

I want just to echo this 'No record matching the input was found'.

**Fixed**
Modified in RegisterController as following

```
    $validator = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('EmailValidation');    
    $email_ch = $this->request->getPost('email_reg');
    if (!$validator->isValid($email_ch)) {
        // email address is invalid; print the reasons
        $model = new ViewModel(array(
            'error' => 'Following email is already registered please try another one',
            'form' => $form,
        ));
        $model->setTemplate('test/register/index');
        return $model;
    }
```

I had compared

```
if (!$validator->isValid($email_ch))
```

Before with nothing and that's why i needed to add first

```
$email_ch = $this->request->getPost('email_reg');
```

Comment: you could do your own method to check for that after form validation but if you want to get your hands dirty then check this question out on how to inject the information you need in the register filter in order to check if record exist. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13818525/how-to-set-db-adapter-to-validator-recordexists-in-zend-framework-2

Comment: Please chem my **Additional** block.

Comment: Here - https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Validator/Db/RecordExists.php. Also now my form isn't registering into DB in case email isn't already registered.

Comment: ok let me read it and test

Comment: Check my **Fixed** part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to do that in your controller, just try this in your `RegisterFilter` class :

**First :** Add `$sm` as parameter of the `_construct()` method :

```
public function __construct($sm) {....}
```

**Second:** Replace e-mail validation by this one :

```
$this->add (  array (
            'name' => 'email_reg',
            'required' => true,
            'validators' => array(
                    array(
                            'name'    => 'Zend\Validator\Db\NoRecordExists',
                            'options' => array(
                                    'table' => 'user',
                                    'field' => 'email',
                                    'adapter' =>  $sm->get ( 'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' ),
                                    'messages' => array(
                                    NoRecordExists::ERROR_RECORD_FOUND => 'e-mail address already exists'
                                    ),
                            ),
                    ),
            ),

    )

    );
```

When you call the `RegisterFilter` don't forget to pass the `serviceLocator` as parameter in your controller :

```
$form->setInputFilter(new RegisterFilter($this->getServiceLocator()));
```

Supposing you have this in your `global.php` File (config\autoload\global.php) :

```
'service_manager' => array(
 'factories' => array(
 'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory',
```

),
   ),

Comment: ***$form->setInputFilter($sm->get('RegisterFilter'));***
 This is how i call it in my Module.php how should i change to ***$form->setInputFilter(new RegisterFilter($this->getServiceLocator()));*** so it would work?

Comment: Everything works fine only problem is that there should'nt be **NoRecordExists::ERROR_RECORD_FOUND** but **\Zend\Validator\Db\NoRecordExists::ERROR_RECORD_FOUND**. Thanks.

Comment: Glad it helps ;) ! Of course you must add this : `use Zend\Validator\Db\NoRecordExists` in order to use `NoRecordExists::ERROR_RECORD_FOUND` directly.

Comment: Hot check in login for for password, i tried with RecordExists validator which works for email but password is MD5 hashed. And it doesn't work.

Comment: Why do you need to check if password already exists (tokken) ?

Comment: When loggin in i checked if email is in DB and then i want to check if password for existing email is Right if Wrong echo "Wrong Password".

Comment: This not the right method to check for user password. For this you should use the Zend `AuthenticationService`.

Comment: Yes and this i should have used for email which works.

Comment: If you want to check for email duplication when registring you should use this code. But for user login there is the Zend `AuthenticationService`.

Answer (score 0):

To your previous request, ("I want just to echo this 'No record matching the input was found'")

```
$validator = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('EmailValidation');    
$email_ch = $this->request->getPost('email_reg');
if (!$validator->isValid($email_ch)) {
    // email address is invalid; print the reasons
      foreach ($validator->getMessages() as $message) {
           $msg = $message;
        }
    $model = new ViewModel(array(
        'error' => $msg,
        'form' => $form,
    ));
    $model->setTemplate('test/register/index');
    return $model;
}
```